# Assign n jobs to m individuals evenly where n jobs are grouped into random x rows

Tags: algorithm, logic

I have n total jobs that are grouped in x rows such that each row 1..x has random number of jobs. These jobs need to be assigned to m individuals such that each row is assigned to single individual only.

Jobs should be tried to assigned evenly.

For eg. Below table has audit count to represent jobs that need to be assigned to M=4 assignee

[image]

What is the best way for assignment?

I have tried some cases but 1 assignee get higher number than rest -
first add count data to dictionary with individual count as key and repetition number as value. Then determine the average value and assign selected auditor rows with count from dictionary until average value +- 15% range is assigned and last auditor gets rest.

Comment: You can always try a brute force approach for such small problems.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I have not written any code, pseudo logic - like first add count data to dictionary with individual count as key and repetition number as value. Then determine the average value and assign selected auditor rows with count from dictionary until average value +- 15% range is assigned and last auditor gets rest.

Comment: @MrSmith42 problem is part of higher assignement job where each batch having similar problem needs to be assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the acceptable solution using brute force method where I tried using Dictionary and Queue to assign the rows with audit counts equally among selected person.